# Unity 2d Player Glow like on off

Tags: unity, c#, game-mechanics, platformer

I want my player to glow like in a loop of on and off for light it emitting and when he touches certain material with different light it should glow with that color

Comment: I tried point light on Player and also the capsules he can pick and there's a collider on the capsule. I just want now to the player to change light color when he hits the capsule and of course some input to go to the original color.

Comment: Is the character a 2D sprite? many times with 2D sprites you can achieve that effect by creating a white shape, then you softly erase the edges into a somewhat transparent gradient. After applying, you will get a nice 2d color changeable glow using minimal resources.

Comment: Remember, this is not a site where we develop features for you on demand. We expect users to have made a start in implementing the feature, and ask questions about specific problems they encounter while implementing it. If you don't know how to make a start, then the best course of action is to work through some intro to Unity tutorials until you have a solid grasp of the fundamentals to be able to make inroads on your own original feature designs.

Comment: Yes its 2d sprite, Can you elaborate on Creating that Shape

Comment: best I can explain it in the comments without uploading a example. just a search for creating 2d glow effect has many examples in image and video form showing the process. should get you on the right path though.